# Finding a file selecting it in finder issue

Tags: osx-lion, applescript, osx-snow-leopard

I am having this script to find a file and select it

```
set filePath to ("filePath.ext" as POSIX file)
tell application "Finder"
    if (exists filePath) then
            select filePath
            activate
    else
        display alert "File " & filePath & " does not exist"
    end if
end tell
```

it is working perfect well on Mac os x 10.6.x (LION) but when I try to run this script on Mac os x 10.5.x (snow-leopard) it is selecting file but taking too much time. Any suggestion how can I make this code work fine on both versions of Mac.
Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT:**
I am selecting file from a network drive and hostel system is having a Windows Os. All systems are located in the same network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `reveal` command may be of assistance to you. It simply locates a file in the finder, opens a new window if necessary, and then selects the file—all that using just one line of code:

```
tell application "Finder" to reveal path:to:some:file
```

The file must actually exist for this to work, of course. You know a particular file/directory exists when it is presented in alias form (I.e. `Macintosh HD:Users:billybob:Desktop:howToHack.pdf`). Attempting to coerce a nonexistent file into an alias will result in an error. If you are 100% certain that the file exists and know exactly where it is, congratulations! You have one less thing to worry about. If your certainty level is anything less than 100%, use a `try-catch` block. They have saved my life on multiple occasions. That way, if you distribute your applications via the Internet like I do, your clients are not presented with undecipherable error messages.

An example of this is demonstrated below:

```
set theFile to "/Users/billybob/Desktop/folder/subfolder/subfolder2/subfolder3/fineByMe.mp3"
try
    set theFile to (theFile) as alias
    tell application "Finder" to reveal theFile
on error
    display alert "The file " & quoted form of theFile & "does not exist."
    -- The variable 'theFile' couldn't be coerced into an alias.
    -- Therefore, 'theFile' still has a string value and it can be used in dialogs/alerts among other things.
end try
```

Is this more efficient or less time consuming than what you've written? I'm not particularly sure, to be honest. However, I have written many scripts that have included the `reveal` command on Mac OS X 10.5.8 (Leopard), Mac OS X 10.6.8 (Snow-Leopard), and Mac OS X 10.7.3 (Lion), and the results have been satisfying.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. I tried reveal command, but didn't find any significant change :(

Comment: @Zaksh I'm sorry to hear that you're unsatisfied. What are your exspectations as far as performance is concerned?

Comment: I just want the script to just as fast as it is working on MAC OS x 10.6 and one thing which I missed is i am selecting file from a network drive and hostel system is having a Windows Os. All systems are in the same network (locally)

Comment: @Zaksh Ahhh retrieving the file from the network just might be your issue. The more recent versions of Mac have improved networking functionality, so Snow-Leopard presumably has something that Leopard doesn't, and I don't believe this is repairable. It *might* be, though. Consider posting the code that retrieves the file off of the network. I may be able to further assist you then. :)

Comment: Thanks for your humble assistance, I map the network drive manually i just pass the file path to my script using custom protocol.

Comment: @Zaksh I'm happy to help you. If you're still unsatisfied, I would go ahead and make a new question regarding the networking issue (don't edit your question so that it becomes a new one—it renders all answers useless. I learned this the hard way, unfortunately).

Answer (score 0):

You have errors in your code.

1. You forgot a period after "exists" in the display alert line.
2. You cannot display a posix file. It must be converted to string. Apple doesn't have this optimization.
3. The exists command will always return false the way you've used it because you didn't provide a full file path. Although java and c++ allow abbreviated file paths, apple does not.

I cannot comment, so I was forced to put this as an answer instead.

Comment: "filePath.ext" mean some valid path with valid extension and as I mention the code is working perfect on MAC OS x 10.6 but it is just a bit slow on MAC OS x 10.5