# in Emacs, how to show current file in Finder?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In Emacs on Mac OSX, is there a function to reveal the current file in the Finder?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A bit late, but I just created a script based on this. When invoked from a dired buffer, it opens the folder.

https://github.com/kaz-yos/reveal-in-osx-finder (new link)

EDIT 2014-02-06
Now available on MELPA: M-x list-packages should list reveal-in-finder among other packages.

See here for use.
https://github.com/kaz-yos/reveal-in-osx-finder

EDIT 2014-04-08
I slightly updated the script (below). This should be helpful in a dired buffer.

(NEW in 0.3.0) If M-x reveal-in-finder is invoked in a dired buffer, it will open the current folder in the OS X Finder. It will also highlight the file at point if available.

EDIT 2015-08-03
The package was renamed to reveal-in-osx-finder.el to avoid possible confusion with other kinds of "finders".

Comment: In what ways is this different/better than the previously accepted answer?

Comment: If M-x reveal-in-finder is invoked in a file-associated buffer, it will open the folder enclosing the file in the OS X Finder. It will also select the file the buffer is associated with within the folder (the "reveal" part).

If M-x reveal-in-finder is invoked in a buffer not associated with a file, it will open the folder defined in the default-directory variable. In a dired buffer, this should open the current folder in the OS X Finder.

Comment: Maybe not yet. I'm trying to get a version with further improvements on MELPA. I'll let you know when it is ready for package.el installation.

Comment: reveal-in-finder.el went into the MELPA repository.
https://github.com/kaz-yos/elisp

If you have configured the MELPA, you can do M-x list-packages and should be able to install it from the menu.

If you have not configured the MELPA, you can follow the instruction below first.
http://melpa.milkbox.net/#/getting-started

Comment: It's really unfortunate that you use the name `finder` without qualification in that library (in the library name and in the library code). `finder.el` is a standard Emacs library, and its commands, functions and variables use the name `finder` to mean something quite different from the "MAC OS X Finder". Please consider using a name and name component such as `macosx-finder` or `osx-finder`, instead of just `finder`.

Comment: @kaz_yos, I use Path Finder, a standard Mac OS X Finder replacement.  When invoking reveal-in-finder, it opens the directory in standard Finder rather than Path Finder.  Any idea?  If I do `bash> open path/to/dir`, it's opened in Path Finder.

Comment: @Drew, I'll consider osx-finder.

Comment: @MengLu Changing the code at line 100 from Finder to Path Finder may work if Path Finder also has reveal command. Things work in Apple Script, so it is not connected to the behavior you have with bash.

https://github.com/kaz-yos/elisp/blob/master/reveal-in-finder.el#L100

Comment: Great - thanks for considering the name change. That will help users looking for your library and users looking for info about `finder.el`.

Comment: I finally updated the package name to "reveal-in-osx-finder.el". It should change when the MELPA maintainers accept my pull request.

[github repo](https://github.com/kaz-yos/reveal-in-osx-finder)

Comment: See my answer for a simple way to do this with org-mode itself

Answer (score 4):

**Solution #1:**:  The second solution below was the initial answer, but I am now using something slightly different that also maximizes the Finder window.  So, here is the alternative solution (which works for directories and files):

```lisp
(defun dired-open-in-finder ()
"This function contemplates that we are in columns view in Finder (Command+3),
rather than list view (Command+2)."
(interactive)
  (let ((path (dired-get-file-for-visit))
        (display-pixel-height (number-to-string (display-pixel-height)))
        (display-pixel-width (number-to-string (display-pixel-width))))
    (when path
      (let* ((maximize
              (concat
                "tell application \"Finder\" to set the bounds of the front Finder window to "
                "{0, 0, " display-pixel-width ", " display-pixel-height "}\n"))
             (script
               (concat
                 "tell application \"Finder\"\n"
                 " set frontmost to true\n"
                 " make new Finder window to (POSIX file \"" path "\")\n"
                 maximize
                 "end tell\n")))
        (start-process "finder" nil "osascript" "-e" script)))))
```

---

**Solution #2**:  I don't remember where I got this from -- if anyone knows, please let me know and I'll post a citation to the author -- thanks.

```lisp
(defun open-finder ()
(interactive)
  (let ((path (or (buffer-file-name) (dired-file-name-at-point)))
          dir file)
    (when path
      (setq dir (file-name-directory path))
      (setq file (file-name-nondirectory path)))
    (open-finder-1 dir file)))

(defun open-finder-1 (dir file)
  (let ((script
      (if file
        (concat
          "tell application \"Finder\"\n"
          " set frontmost to true\n"
          " make new Finder window to (POSIX file \"" (expand-file-name dir) "\")\n"
          " select file \"" file "\"\n"
          "end tell\n")
        (concat
          "tell application \"Finder\"\n"
          " set frontmost to true\n"
          " make new Finder window to {path to desktop folder}\n"
          "end tell\n"))))
    (start-process "osascript-getinfo" nil "osascript" "-e" script)))
```

Comment: This is great. Seems like it's a little bit less "Reveal in Finder" and a little bit more "Open Enclosing Folder." There's no easy way to make it select the actual file in the Finder is there?

Comment: I see there's a "select file" line in there. Doesn't seem to be working though. Would this be of any use? `tell application "Finder" to reveal path:to:some:file` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222501/finding-a-file-selecting-it-in-finder-issue

Comment: @Peter Salazar  Thank you for the suggestion and link -- I'll take a look.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an Emacs function and so perhaps not what you're after, but if you're using Cocoa-built Emacs (apple-appkit) the simplest solution is to ⌘-click or ⌃-click on the filename in the menu bar, then click on the enclosing folder, which will then open in Finder.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but let me add one solution. So far I am happy with this.

```
(defun open-current-file-in-finder ()
  (interactive)
  (shell-command "open -R ."))
```

Answer (score 2):

Improving on diadochos' answer.
This is for OSX system. It can be easily changed to any unix or gnu based operating systems.

This actually opens the parent directory (not directory containing the file)

```
(defun open-current-file-in-finder ()
  (interactive)
  (shell-command "open -R ."))
```

This is what I was looking for. To open the directory containing the file.

```
(defun open-current-file-directory ()
  (interactive)
  (shell-command "open ."))
```

### Final Answer

```
(defun show-in-finder ()
  (interactive)
  (shell-command (concat "open -R " buffer-file-name)))
```

Tested in Emacs 25.1.1

Answer (score 0):

On dired mode, instead of 'e' or 'f' to open the file within an emacs buffer, type '!' and then "open -R". A new Finder window is opened pointing to your file.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just type the following.

```
M-:
open .
```

when you have the file opened in current buffer.

The benefit is you don't need to remember the function's name, not even part of it in order to get an auto-completion.

Comment: Where did you get this command? it appears to be unavailable.

Comment: It's `! open .` not `M-: open .`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to write a `file://...` link in your Org document e.g.

```
file://Users/my_username/Backups/
```

Now, bring your cursor to anywhere in that link and run `M-x org-open-at-point` (I bind this to `s-.` in my org-mode-map for simplicity)

---

You can also press `C-c C-l` to edit the link and give it a human readable title.